# correct way to structure domains for a jquery api?

Tags: jquery

if i have a website at [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com),

and i was thinking to set up my client side jquery that collects data to go to api.domain.com so its nice and tidy, but we cant do that because its cross site scripting. how do website architects structure their api services when restricted like this?

do you have to make a load balancer to pick up [www.domain.com/api/](http://www.domain.com/api/) and send that to your api infrastructure? I was hoping to completely separate website services from the api services that serve them.

Comment: For jQuery script like the .js file?

Comment: no not the js file, the ajax URL that any async jquery calls make.